# Oracle update trigger on the same table

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I want to update field `data_aktualizacji` when some row in the same table  is updated. I created the following compound trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER oferta_update_trigger
FOR UPDATE ON oferty
compound TRIGGER
  id_oferty number(10);

  AFTER EACH ROW IS
    BEGIN
      id_oferty := :new.idk;
  END AFTER EACH ROW;

  AFTER STATEMENT IS
    BEGIN
      UPDATE oferty SET data_aktualizacji = SYSDATE WHERE idk = id_oferty;
  END AFTER STATEMENT;
END;
/
```

When I want to update some record, I get the following error.

```
SQL Error: ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded.
```

How to solve this problem? I this that some loop is created, but I don't know, how to workaround this.

Comment: All you need is `:new.data_aktualizacji=SYSDATE`. Remove AFTER STATEMENT, change `AFTER EACH ROW` to `BEFORE EACH ROW`

Comment: Well, a compound trigger isn't something you **have to** use every time you hear a word "trigger". It did help sorting the *mutating table* issue you have had out, but that's something quite different - you are updating the same table trigger is created on, so - no need for that.
DEFAULT column value would by my choice (as suggested by @Ctznkane525). If you still want to use a trigger, do what @wolfrevokcats said (with a minor mistake; it is ":=", not "=".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update oracle to alter the column to default to sysdate

```
Alter table oferty alter column data_aktualizacji set default sysdate
```

No need for trigger at all

Comment: This works only as intended if the inserted column value is NULL, I.e not provided.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - if you are changing the data as you insert it...then that would be the most logical thing to do...to not provide it...if you did provide it...what would the value be...and for what purpose

Comment: The intention is quite clear: For **every** UPDATE set `data_aktualizacji = SYSDATE` A default value does not provide this. It works on INSERT and only if value is not provided (or given as `DEFAULT`). Actually it would never set desired value except on `UPDATE oferty SET data_aktualizacji = DEFAULT`

Answer (score 0):

As Ctznkane525 wrote, you definitively should use `default`-value to perform this action.

If you don't want to use `default` you can modify `new.data_aktualizacji`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER oferty_update_aktualizacji
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON oferty
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
   :new.data_aktualizacji:= sysdate;
END;
```